# how could I get checkbox value in email after submit from https://formsubmit.co?

Tags: html

hi I use https://formsubmit.co as form submit.

I could use select and text input, but I couldn't get value from checkbox.

```
 <label class="container" for="subscription">subscription
      <input
         type="checkbox"
         checked="checked"
         name="subscription"
         value="on"
         id="subscription"
       />
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

How could I get checkbox value in email after submit?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkbox value is not sent when it's unchecked, that's how HTML works. In order to send *unchecked* value, put hidden field *before* checkbox with same name and default *unchecked* value:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>FormSubmit Demo</h1>
  <form target="_blank" action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="subscription" value="off">

    <label class="container" for="subscription">subscription
      <input
         type="checkbox"
         checked="checked"
         name="subscription"
         value="on"
         id="subscription"
       />
       <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-block">Submit Form</button>
  </form>
</div>
```